# running python in admin console still throwing WindowsError Error 5 Access is denied

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script which is suppose to recurively remove corrupt code I am working with.

```
import shutil
import subprocess

path = subprocess.check_output("echo %APPDATA%", shell=True)
path = "%s\\" % path[:-2]
shutil.rmtree("%sPub\\Cache\\" % path)
```

and it fails at the rmtree call.  It looks like it fails in the rmtree call at:

```
os.remove(fullname)
```

and then it will throw the error saying:

*WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: '.............'*

I have tried both running this in a regular shell and an admin shell and im not sure what is going on.  Maybe the subprocess launched by os.remove is not admin?  I figured those rights would be passed into the child processes forked by my python script.

Thoughts?

Comment: What is the actual directory that your code is attempting to remove?

Comment: im trying to delete everything under the * Pub\Cache\ * directory.  It is a bunch of stuff related to the outdated datasets from Dart's (The language) package management system

Comment: When you get the "Access denied" error, did any of the files get deleted? What happens if you try to delete the directory from Explorer?

Comment: As a side note, there are cleaner ways to fetch environment variables (`os.environ['APPDATA']`) and build paths from individual components (`os.path.join(basepath,dir1,dir2,...)`).

Comment: When deleting the items from explorer, they all delete.  Was about 250mb worth of data clean up.  Also, i really shouldve thought more on it.  Should i have just did:  `path = "%sPub\\Cache\\" % os.environ["APPDATA"]` ?

Comment: Your Python code isn't trying to just delete the contents of that directory - it's trying to delete the **directory itself**, an additional step that could fail. Your "Access is denied" message should have indicated which file it was unable to delete - was that file in use by another application at the time?

Comment: yeah my goal was to delete the folder and all of its contents.  The error was: WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\wfrancis\\AppData\\Roaming\\Pub\\Cache\\git\\cache\\seg_ui-7212c90ba70f88fb83440f8049e5d6ee9e2276ef\\objects\\pack\\pack-053cf44e4ba619c904614642a957e2d44688ba54.idx'

Comment: It seems like there was a subfolder called git (as you can see in the above comment) that it didnt like.  When i repopulated the area the script worked.  Something in that git subdirectory though is not really liked by the `os.remove`function

Comment: Related: [How to avoid “WindowsError: \[Error 5\] Access is denied”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37830326/3357935)