# Deleting files from download folder using Python

Tags: python, delete-file, removeall

I am trying to delete files from my download folder but I get and error that read `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\Downloads'`

I tried running Visual Studio as admin and adding a code to elevate privileges but I still get the error

my code is

```
ASADMIN = 'asadmin'

if sys.argv[-1] != ASADMIN:
    script = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
    params = ' '.join([script] + sys.argv[1:] + [ASADMIN])
    shell.ShellExecuteEx(lpVerb='runas', lpFile=sys.executable, lpParameters=params)

def deleteFiles():
    folder = "C:\\Users\\Downloads"
    for f in glob.glob(folder):
        os.remove(f)
    return;

deleteFiles()
```

can anyone help with getting these files deleted? Thanks

Comment: You as a user do not have rights to that folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid "WindowsError: \[Error 5\] Access is denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830326/how-to-avoid-windowserror-error-5-access-is-denied)

Comment: `glob.glob('C:\\Users\\Downloads')` does NOT return a list of files in that directory; it returns the directory name itself.  Perhaps you meant `glob.glob('C:\\Users\\Downloads\\*.*')` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glob.glob()` returns a list of all filenames matching a wildcard expression.  i.e. if you passed it `'/tmp/*.py'`, it might return the list `['/tmp/bar.py', '/tmp/baz.py', 'tmp/foo.py']`.

You passed it a string which contains no wildcard characters, so it just returned the original string back to you, so your code ended up calling `os.remove('C:\\Users\\Downloads')`.

Comment: thanks, I just noticed that too. I put in the `*` and it worked