# Python access is denied when I open image

Tags: python, image, pip, python-imaging-library

[image]

Above is the pic of the error and my code. Whenever I try to show the image, **Access is denied**. May I know how can I fix this problem? I have installed PIL and imported simpleImage. It was ok before when I tried a month ago.

Comment: are you on windows 10? edit: Oh I just opened screenshot and I see that you are using windows

Comment: Yes, I am on windows 10. Sorry, I should've mentioned it in the caption.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Close PyCharm. Right click PyCharm, open as Administrator.

Edit1:

If that doesn't work, try the following steps->
Open file explorer.
Go to the folder, or folders, you wish to write in.
Right-Click on it.
Select Properties.
In the properties window select the security tab.
Click Edit and edit it as you wish or need to give access to programs or users.

source->
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37831625/7359221

Comment: Thanks a lot, the first one works. I tried the second way, no matter how many times I changed my permission, it's still said "access is denied" !

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad this worked for you. If you mark the answer correct, it will help others in the future know this is a valid solution. Cheers

Comment: oh sure, I will do it. I am new here so there's still a lot of things I'm unfamiliar with. Thanks for telling!

Comment: A risky solution from a security point of view.